# Get the new files/directories created after date/Timestamp in a hierarchy of directory in Windows

Tags: windows, file-search

Is it possible to find the files and directories created within a direcotry hierarchy in Windows.

For example : getting all the files inside "dir1" directory and all his subdirectory hierarchy created Today after 10 AM?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `datecreated:>10:00 AM` in the search box at the top-right of the Windows explorer window?

Formulated as an *interrogative sentence* because I use 24-hours time:

[image: DateCreated_GTR_0420.png]

Another approach: sort search results by the *Date created* column and select desired as follows:

[image: DateCreated_today.png]

Resources:

- [Windows Search Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362(VS.85).aspx#user_interface)
- [Windows Search Features](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744686(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [Advanced tips for searching in Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/advanced-tips-for-searching-in-windows)
- [How to Use Windows’ Advanced Search Features: Everything You Need to Know](http://www.howtogeek.com/173703/how-to-use-windows-advanced-search-features-everything-you-need-to-know/)
- [Advanced Query Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The Advanced Query Syntax (AQS) is used by Microsoft Windows Desktop
>   Search (WDS) to help users and programmers better define and narrow
>   their searches. Using AQS is an easy way to narrow searches and
>   deliver better result sets. Searches can be narrowed by the following
>   parameters:
>
> - File kinds: folders, documents, presentations, pictures and so on.
> - File stores: specific databases and locations.
> - File properties: size, date, title and so on.
> - File contents: keywords like "project deliverables," "AQS," "blue suede shoes," and so on.
>
> Furthermore, search parameters can be combined using search
>   operators...